# Updating a TextView causes instant crash

Tags: android

Im updating a textView with a method in a class,when i run the application i get this error:

```
A/libc: Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 (SI_TKILL)
```

I have looked at another question on stackoverflow but is another type of programm that involves a webview so it didnt help much.I have tried to use the debugger to find the error but it crashes anyway.
This is the code of my mainActivity:

```
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        super.onPostExecute(s);
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
            dati.status = jsonObject.getString("status");
            dati.totalResults = jsonObject.getInt("totalResults");
            String articles = jsonObject.getString("articles");
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(articles);

            for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++){
                JSONObject jsonPart = arr.getJSONObject(i);
                String source = jsonPart.getString("source");
                JSONObject jsonPart2 = new JSONObject(source);
                Source s1 = new Source(jsonPart2.getString("id"),jsonPart2.getString("name"));
                dati.articoli.put(i, new Article(s1,jsonPart.getString("author"),jsonPart.getString("title"),
                        jsonPart.getString("description"),jsonPart.getString("url"),jsonPart.getString("urlToImage"),jsonPart.getString("publishedAt"),
                        jsonPart.getString("content")));
            }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        dati.stampaDati(0,txt_articolo,txt_contatore);
    }
```

This is my Dati Class

```
    public class Dati {
public String status;
public int totalResults;
public ArrayMap<Integer,Article> articoli = new ArrayMap<Integer, Article>();

public void stampaDati(int articoloCorrente, TextView txt_articolo,TextView txt_contatore){
    Log.i("asd",Integer.toString(this.totalResults));
    txt_contatore.setText("articolo "+(articoloCorrente+1)+" di "+Integer.toString(this.totalResults));
    txt_articolo.setText("Autore:"+articoli.get(articoloCorrente).sourceA.name);
}}
```

I know that the json is parsed correctly so the problem should be with the textView.
Can some one help me figuring out what is the porblem and the meaning of the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this `Integer.toString(this.totalResults)` to `String.valueOf(totalResults)`
And you should not have string concatenations in `textView.setText()`

E.g.

```
String displayStr1 = "articolo "+(articoloCorrente+1)+" di "+ String.valueOf(this.totalResults);
txt_contatore.setText(displayStr1);
String displayStr2 = "Autore:"+articoli.get(articoloCorrente).sourceA.name;
txt_articolo.setText(displayStr2)
```